# Have a lot of optional data that user can download. where to start from?

Tags: java, android, download

In my android app I have a lot of files that users can optionally download. The files are between 5 to 500 mb of data (mp3, txt files,...).

I thought I should zip each section so the app downloads 1 file and then extracts it, even if this mean I have to work hard before the release to zip everything and have all options covered. Is there a better way?

The app on the first run download 15 mb that are essential for the app to work, and then the user can download additional data.

Where should I start from? I thought I should make downloading in the background and notify the user of the progress in the drop-down menu.. Is this the best way to do this? How can I do this?

My apps target is 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a download Service for your application that can handle downloading these files in the background.  You should include current progress in the notification bar, as you have suggested, and you should give the user the ability to pause/resume downloads.  When your app first starts up, it should check to see if the necessary files have been downloaded; if not, it should begin downloading them with your Service and explain to the user that the files are being downloaded.